# Codeigniter: Image Upload image validation not working

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to check if the upload file field (`<input type="file" name="userfile">`) is empty or other validation on image upload field. In the **view** I echo  `<?php echo $upload_error;?>` but it says `$upload_error` is Undefined variable. what is the problem with my code and how can i fix that.

**This is my controller function**

```
function add_main_products(){
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('product_name', 'Main Product Category', 'required');


            if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE){
                $this->load->view('admin/admin_add_mainproduct');
            }
            else{

                $config['upload_path'] = 'application/views/uploads/';               
                $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg';                
                $this->load->library('upload', $config);

                if (! $this->upload->do_upload('userfile')){
                    $error['upload_error'] = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

                    $this->load->view('admin/admin_add_mainproduct', $error);

                    return FALSE;
                }

                $this->mod_products->add_main_product($this->upload->data());
                $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
                $data['result']="Main Product Added Successfully";
                $this->load->view('admin/admin_add_mainproduct', $data);    
           }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand your question properly but you can set rules the same way for file input:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('userfile', 'Image', 'required');
```

Let me know if this helps

Comment: Did you put it right under `$this->form_validation->set_rules('product_name', 'Main Product Category', 'required');`??